# what is the app/bootstrap.php file for?

Tags: magento-1.9, architecture

I just started working on a new magento site and when I moved it to my local I got the below error on my nginx server.

> 2016/09/14 13:38:41 [error] 7#7: *13 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP
>   message: PHP Warning:  require(/var/www/html/app/bootstrap.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /var/www/html/index.php on line 64

I simply removed that line from *index.php*, but what's that file for?  Why is it in some Magento installs?  It's a Magento ver. 1.9.0.1 install.

Comment: Hi there, check the answer & give feedback ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**app/bootstrap.php** file should be provided in the package you have used

Anyways, in Magento 1.9 that file just provides a workaround for some libxml PHP bugs

```
/**
 * Apply workaround for the libxml PHP bugs:
 * @link https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=62577
 * @link https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=64938
 */

if (function_exists('libxml_disable_entity_loader')) {
    libxml_disable_entity_loader(false);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Bootstrap.php performs essential initialization required to run magento you can find more detail [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/bootstrap/magento-bootstrap.html)

Comment: does this file come with every Magento install and/or version?  Should I add this file because it's not there?

Comment: Yes it is default file in magento package in the folder app/bootstrap.php Also you should never comment including of the same from index.php

Comment: they're the dev docs for Magento 2, not Magento 1